# Bootstrap collapse button not working due to jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

So i'm working on **fullcalendar** and integrated it with **AdminLTE**. I've got my desired output

[image]

but later on I realized that the bootstrap collapse button is not working or reacting and also the other clickable features. I've tried to check the scripts and figured out that it has something to do with `<script src='fullcalendar-2.5.0/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>` because when I tried to remove it, it works again but the calendar became like this [image]

This is my scripts: Does it have something to do with the order of the scripts although I've already tried to put jquery.min.js on top and still, nothing happened. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 <!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
    <script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
    <script>
      $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
    </script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <script src="bootstrap/js/moment.js"></script>
    <!-- Morris.js charts -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Sparkline -->
    <script src="plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jvectormap -->
    <script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
    <script src="plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js"></script>
    <!-- daterangepicker -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <!-- datepicker -->
    <script src="plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Slimscroll -->
    <script src="plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
    <script src="dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
    <script src="dist/js/demo.js"></script>

    <script src='fullcalendar-2.5.0/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='fullcalendar-2.5.0/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
  <script src='fullcalendar-2.5.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
```

calendar html:

```
 <div class="box box-danger table-responsive">
                  <div class="box-header">
                     <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    <h3 class="box-title">Calendar</h3>
                    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                       <button class="btn btn-box-tool  pull-right " data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Add</button>
                          <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
     <!-- Modal --> </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
                  </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                  <div class="box-body pad">




                    <div id='calendar'></div>




                  </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                </div><!-- /.box -->
```

Comment: can you show me you html code?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<button class="btn btn-box-tool  pull-right " data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
</button>
```

Or if that does not work try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn-box-tool").click(function(){
    $("#calendar").slideUp("slow");
  });
});
```